# If $A$ is invertible and $(A-B)C = B(A^{-1})$, prove that $C(A-B) = (A^{-1})B$

Tags: matrices

Let $A, B, C$ be square matrices of order $3×3$ with real elements. If $A$ is invertible and $(A-B)C = B(A^{-1})$ , then prove that $C(A-B) = (A^{-1})B$.

The question has not any information about B and C that it is invertible or not. So we can't apply inverse both side in the equation.

Answer (score 0):

From the first condition, one gets $ACA = BCA + B$.
Then
$$
AC(A-B)-B = ACA-ACB-ACA+BCA=BCA-ACB
$$
I do not see how this can be zero without further assumptions.

Comment: See the edited question. Can you convert the last equation in that form?